# Apply an Autofilter in table using VBA in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with prices and products. I want to filter by excluding the price if it is 0,00 € or if it returns the word ERROR. I do the following:

```
Set tbl = Worksheets("FOR EXPORT").ListObjects("Table1")
'SET AUTOFILTER
tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>*ERROR*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="<>0"
```

Nothing is filtered, neither criterion 1 or criterion 2

I tested Criteria2:="<>0,00 €" as well with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is you need an AND operator, not an OR. Everything in the world meets one of those conditions - OR - so nothing will be filtered. You also wouldn't include formatting like the Euro sign, unless this is a column of text. :

```
Field:=3, Criteria1:= "<>*Error*", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>0"
```

Comment: Yes! its working and next what is the safest way to copy the filtered table in different worksheet? 

I use Worksheets("TEMP").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Set tbl2 = Worksheets("TEMP").ListObjects("table2")

Comment: If that works for you then you should use it. If not, then consider asking another question. By the way, I got the answer above by using the Macro Recorder. If you're not using it then consider doing so. It's a great way to start writing code for which you don't know the syntax, and to try to figure out the best way to do things.

Comment: from jitbit.com?

Comment: https://www.contextures.com/excel-macro-record-test.html. It's a built-in Excel feature. This is more about how to use it to automate tasks, so doesn't mention that you can then open the macro in VBA by finding the module created by the recorder, e.g., Module1.